# cant generate random number in omnetpp

Tags: random, ini, omnet++

I have define host traffic send interval in this way in my NED file and I expect to receive different number in every execution:

```
    volatile double sendInterval @unit("s") = default(exponential(1s));
```

but it gives me same result in every execution, where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any problem here. This is a feature. Any *random* number in OMNeT++ is actually a *pseudo-random* number.
And they really **need to be deterministic**, so every experiment can be exactly **reproduced**.

See the manual section: https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:sim-lib:random-number-generators

Where it says:

> Starting from the same seed, RNGs always produce the same sequence of random numbers. This is a useful property and of great importance, because it makes simulation runs repeatable.

To get different values, try setting a different `seed-set` for your configuration in the `.ini` file, or running multiple repetitions by adjusting the `repeat` option - each repetition automatically sets a different seed for the PRNGs.

Also see: https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:config-sim:repeating-runs-with-different-seeds

Comment: I need to execute my simulation 500 times using Cmdenv, each one with different values, I'm using seed set with repeat set to 500 but the send interval is remaining the same in all repeat, what should I do?

Comment: Adding `repeat` alone will make all the seeds different. By also setting the `seed-set` option, you overwrite this, and set the same value for all runs.